# How to read input until next occurrence in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the problems is that given the below input, I would like to separate every urls (that start with either [URL or [LINK or [WEBSITE) and the text. I would like to put every URLs in order into a list and every text into a text.

I also would like to combine every text into one line. So that every link matches with its corresponding text. Below is an example.

```
[URL - https://url1.com]
news_line1 word
news_line2 word word
news_line3 word word word

[LINK - https://url2.com]
headline_line1 letter
headline_line2 letter letter
headline_line3 letter letter letter

[WEBSITE - https://url3.com]
date_line1 sentence
date_line2 sentence sentence
date_line3 sentence sentence sentence
```

output would be
Links:

```
[URL - https://url1.com]
[LINK - https://url2.com]
[WEBSITE - https://url3.com]
```

and
Text:

```
news_line1 word news_line2 word word news_line3 word word word
headline_line1 letter headline_line2 letter letter headline_line3 letter letter letter
date_line1 sentence date_line2 sentence sentence date_line3 sentence sentence sentence
```

The current code I have is

```
import sys

inFile = sys.argv[1]

with open(inFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content]
url_links = []
sentences = []

for entry in content:
    sentence = ""
    if entry.startswith(("[news_text", "[headline", "[date")):
        url_links.append(entry)

    else:
        sentence = sentence + entry

    sentences.append(sentence)

for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence)
```

And the current output I have is

```
news_line1 word
news_line2 word word
news_line3 word word word


headline_line1 letter
headline_line2 letter letter
headline_line3 letter letter letter


date_line1 sentence
date_line2 sentence sentence
date_line3 sentence sentence sentence
```

How can I tweak it such that it give me the correct output?

Comment: If you want the output on one line, why not play around with `print(sentence, end='')`to chop off the newline included with each `print()`statement by default?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add unnecessary empty lines to your output you should add this to your loop

```
if not entry:
    continue
```

To get output you want, you can utilize string's [join method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
result = ''.join(sentences)
print(result)
```

To split your text into blocks, let's add a boolean variable showing if there was a block end (block ends when new `url_link` starts being processed).

```
previous_block_end = False
for entry in content:
    if not entry:
        continue

    sentence = ""
    if entry.startswith(("[URL", "[LINK", "[WEBSITE")):
        previous_block_end = True
        url_links.append(entry)
    else:
        sentence = sentence + entry
        if previous_block_end and len(url_links) > 1:
            sentence = '\n' + sentence
        if not previous_block_end:
            sentence = ' ' + sentence
        previous_block_end = False

    sentences.append(sentence)

result = ''.join(sentences)
print(result)
```

Comment: if I do join then everything would be in one line though. I am trying to keep every article in separate lines. So every text under [URL etc would be in one line.

Comment: I've edited my answer with code adding new line after each block

Comment: This surely accomplishes the task! But it doesn't output the correct output. When the mulpitle lines are joining together, it just puts them together without a space. When I do    ' '.join instead it adds empty space beginning of every line after the first line. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am getting '''news_line1 wordnews_line2 word wordnews_line3 word word wordheadline_line1 letter''' for example. where it should be '''news_line1 word news_line2 word word news_line3 word word word''' Given the example input, it's not outputting the correct output

Comment: @JoeyJoestar, could you please take a look? :)

Answer (score 0):

Use list to store sentence elements, remember startswith() is case sensitive, relevant part of code after modifications below:

```
url_links = []
sentences = []
sentence = []
for entry in s.split('\n'):    # s holds your string
    entry.strip()
    if entry.startswith(("[URL", "[LINK", "[WEBSITE")):
        url_links.append(entry)
        if sentence:    # add only not empty list
            sentences.append(' '.join(sentence))
        sentence = [] 
    else:
        if entry: sentence.append(entry)
else:   # this else belongs to for
    if sentence: sentences.append(' '.join(sentence))


for sentence in sentences:
    print(sentence)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the input text has newline in between. So, s.split(\n) would possibly split one thing into multiple texts.

Comment: Please share input sample where the code fails. If \n marks end of line it should  work.